# Conditionally Assign a Libname in SAS

Tags: sas, macros, sas-macro

I want to conditionally assign a libname in sas based on a already set macro variable, for one option of this if statement I also want to include a datastep. This is what I'm currently trying:

```
 %if &stress_test.= "N" %then %do;
    %let agg = c:users/me/library1;
    libname agg         "&agg." access=readonly;
    
    %else %do;
    %let agg = c:users/me/library2;
    libname agg         "&agg.";
    
    DATA AGG.Want.;
    SET AGG.HAVE.;
    RUN;
    
    %end;
```

But it doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated and happy to try a different method as it's the first time I'm trying something along these lines.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error or simply a different result to what you expect?

Comment: It doesn't seem to listen to the if statement, when I run %let stress_test= N; it still ends up doing the second option.

Comment: If you run %let stress_test= N and then the code above, then it will take the second option because N is not equal to "N" in the SAS Macro Language.

Comment: @PeterClemmensen Right!!! Thank you, that makes sense and I believe I over thought the whole thing. When it was just a simple action.

Comment: see a small example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses what I think is your first problem: getting the %if-%then-%else to work properly. I suspect that you do not realize that the SAS Macro language is a text langauge. So `"N"` is not the same as `N`.

See the small example below.

```
%macro test;

   %let stress_test = N;

   %if &stress_test = "N" %then %put ONE;
   %if &stress_test = N   %then %put TWO;

%mend;

%test
```

Answer (score 1):

Three issues with above mentioned code

1. You cannot create  datasets in library in which you have read only access. 2. you do not have %end statement after first %do loop.
2. datastep is common for both, so you have to keep outside of %if %then otherwise it is not available for one of the condition. Also  libname statement is repeated and you can keep out of the conditional statements

below code has worked for me

```
    %let stress_test = "N";
    %if &stress_test.="N" %then %do;
         %let agg = /home/kiranvenna1/abc/;
    %end;
    %else %do;
          %let agg = /home/kiranvenna1/allmyfiles/;
    %end;

libname agg "&agg.";

    DATA AGG.Want;
        SET AGG.a;
    RUN;
```